# How do I register a directive in a custom module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive but the .directive code is never executed. I'm sure the problem is something obvious, but I can't see it:

[Example on Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZbNkda9ffdkxkxrR0G5t?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="app">

  <responsive-parent>xxx</responsive-parent>

</div>

<script>
angular.module("mrpmorris.responsive-parent", [])
    .directive("responsive-parent", [
    "$window", "$timeout",
    function ($window, $timeout) {
        console.log("**** THIS IS NEVER REACHED ****");
        return new mrpmorris.responsiveParent.Directive($window, $timeout);
    }
]);

var mrpmorris;
(function (mrpmorris) {
    var responsiveParent;
    (function (responsiveParent) {
        var Directive = (function () {
            function Directive($window, $timeout) {
                var _this = this;
                this.$window = $window;
                this.$timeout = $timeout;
                this.restrict = "E";
                this.template = "<h1>It works</h1>";
                this.replace = true;
            }
            return Directive;
        }());
        responsiveParent.Directive = Directive;
    })(responsiveParent = mrpmorris.responsiveParent || (mrpmorris.responsiveParent = {}));
})(mrpmorris || (mrpmorris = {}));



    angular.module("app", ["mrpmorris.responsive-parent"]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive should be named `responsiveParent`, not `responsive-parent`.

It would still be used using `responsive-parent`in the view, though.

This is all explained in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#).